# How to get the value of ':set modified?' in a Vim function

Tags: vim, scripting

I'm new to Vim scripting, but I haven't found the answer to my question on the interwebs, maybe it's too easy...

I'd like to do a script that opens a new buffer in a split window if the current buffer is modified, otherwise it opens the buffer in the current window.

I know that `:set modified?` will tell me if the current buffer is modified, but I can't find a way to call that in a function.

I'd like something like that:

```
function! SmartOpen()
    if (:set modified? == 'modified')
        " open in a new window
    else
        " open in the same window
endfunction
```

Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an ampersand to get the value of a setting. Do this:

```
function! SmartOpen()
    if &modified
        " open in a new window
    else
        " open in the same window
endfunction
```

Since `&modified` returns a boolean (well, technically an int `0` or `1`), you don't need to string compare it.

Somre more info about accessing settings like this can be found in [chapter 19 of *Learn Vimscript the Hard Way*](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/19.html).

I've looked around for some helpfiles about this feature, but I can't find any since

```
:h &
```

is about the normal-mode command, and

```
:h :&
```

is about the `&` command.

Comment: It's mentionned in `:h expression-syntax`, and `:h :let-&`